# How to make text look realistic on scanned paper

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Please kindly teach me how to create the blurry effect for the background where I will type in words to make them more realistic (the illustration below is what I want to achieve after all)
Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Please do not delete a question just because it has been answered. The point of this site is not only to help you but also further visitors. Also, deleting deprives answerers of the possibility to gain some recognition for their effort. If an answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just save it as a jpg, zero quality. Repeat if it's not blurry enough.
Increase/re-scale the size of the imported image.
Font & background colour optional.

[image]

[image]